# Display rows with the highest date attribute for the ones that share the same first name

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

[image: Desc]

I want to display the record with the highest slot date for the records that share the same first name. How would I proceed on doing that?

Comment: i have no clue thats why i want a headsup

Comment: it is much easier if you post the text of your SQL query instead of a screenshot.

Comment: set search_path = 'project';

select E.firstname,S.category , S.showname ,O.slotdate
from hostsshows H , Shows S , Host E ,timeslot O
where S.shownumber = H.shownumber
AND H.empnum = E.empnum
AND O.shownumber = H.shownumber

Comment: We *very much* prefer text over images for code. One cannot copy/paste from images.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the `ROW_NUMBER` windowed function to accomplish this. 
See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS
and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
SELECT E.firstname
    , S.category 
    , S.showname 
    , O.slotdate
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY E.firstname ORDER BY O.slotdate DESC) as rowNum
FROM hostshows H , Shows S , Host E ,timeslot O
WHERE S.shownumber = E.shownumber
AND H.empnum = E.empnum
AND O.shownumber = H.shownumber
) t
WHERE rowNum = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbook example for [**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.firstname)
       e.firstname, s.category, s.showname, o.slotdate
FROM   shows     s 
JOIN   host      e USING (shownumber)
JOIN   timeslot  o USING (shownumber)
JOIN   hostshows h USING (empnum)
ORDER  BY e.firstname, o.slotdate DESC;
```

Detailed explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)